# Keyup event in focused input when clicked link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a button and when it have clicked I show some input field.
The input field tracks keyup events itself.

When I click the button using my keyboard (focus it then hit <kbd>return</kbd>) the input field receives an unexpected `keyup` event.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LpXGM/3/ (just hit <kbd>return</kbd> and look at the messages on the page)

But if I add a timeout everything works as expected. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8BRmK/1/ (no `keyup` event when hitting <kbd>return</kbd> on the button)

Why does this strange thing happen? And how can I fix it?

The code with the handlers:

```
$button.on("click", function(){
    showModal();
});

$emailField.on("keyup", function(event) {
    // process the event
});

var showModal = function() {
    $modal.show();
    $emailField.focus();
}
```

Comment: It happens because the keyup event fires after the click event, and by that time the focus is already in the input. When you use a timeout you defer the execution of the function that inserts the input, so it doesn't have focus when the keyup fires.

Comment: @adeneo Why is the keyup event fired? Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg23y/ when I hit return on the button no btn.keyup event fired.

Comment: Again, the keyup event fires after the click, so  the focus has already switched to the input, so why would a keyup event be fired on the button ?

Comment: @adeneo oh, I see, thanks. Btw, that fiddle was wrong. The right one: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg23y/2/ (if comment out `modal.show` keyup event will be fired)

Comment: @adeneo If you hit space then keyup will be fired BEFORE click. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution without timeOut: http://jsfiddle.net/agudulin/3axBA/

```
$button.on("keypress", function(event){
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    return false;
  }
});

$button.on("keyup", function(event){
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    showModal();
    $status.append($("<span>enter has been pressed</span></br>"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$button.on("keyup mouseup", function(){`

or `$emailField.on("keypress", function(event) {`

Comment: I don't want to use keypres event because it's not the same as keydown and not very official: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".btn",function(e){
       $status.append($("<span>btn click</span></br>"));
    });
    $(document).on("keyup",".email",function(e){
        $status.append($("<span>keyup " + event.keyCode + "</span></br>"));
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

yes its happens because one you click the keyboard than the button click event fire first and than as per your logic your input field take focus and your keyup event is fire. but when you give Timeout so click event is fire first but because of timeout your logic is delayed and than your your keyup event done our work so the focus in not in your input that why it not enter any word in your input.

Comment: Why is the keyup event fired? Look at this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Xg23y when I hit return on the button no btn.keyup event fired.

Comment: please run the fiddle and than press enter